# G++ not finding <iostream.h> in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, g++, ubuntu-9.10

I just installed Ubuntu and tried making the famed "Hello World" program to make sure that all the basics were working.  For some reason though, g++ fails to compile my program with the error: "'cout' is not a member of 'std'".  I've installed the build-essential package.  Am I missing something else?

```
#include <iostream.h>

int main() {
   std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Looks pretty good to me...

Comment: please link to your tutorial or book, so we can spank the authors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't g++ find iostream.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103108/why-cant-g-find-iostream-h)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `#include <iostream>` - `iostream.h` is not standard and may differ from the standard behaviour.

See e.g. the [C++ FAQ lite entry](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/coding-standards.html#faq-27.4) on the matter.

Answer (score 6):

The standard header is called `<iostream>`, not `<iostream.h>`. Also, it is agood idea to compile your C++code with the -Wall and -pedantic flags, which can point out lots of errors with non-standard code that g++ would otherwise ignore. Use:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic myprog.cpp
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it *did* find `iostream.h` but it does not define `cout` in the `std` namespace.  It is there for backwards compatibility with older programs that expect `cout` to be in the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
```

without namespace you won't be able to use cout or cin