# Why can't g++ find iostream.h?

Tags: c++, g++

I'm trying to understand how to compile C++ programs from the command line using g++ and (eventually) Clang on Ubuntu.

I found a webpage which explains MakeFiles and I am following their directions. http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

I downloaded the four example files into their own directory.

- main.cpp
- hello.cpp
- factorial.cpp
- functions.h

I then went ahead and ran their example of how to manually compile without a MakeFile.

```
g++ main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp -o hello
```

When I ran the command from above, I received the following error from g++:

```
main.cpp:1:22: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
hello.cpp:1:22: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

My only experience with writing c++ is using an IDE such as VS C++ Express or CodeBlocks. Isn't the compiler supposed to know what iostream.h is and where to find it?

How do I get rid of this error so the program willl compile?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is no `iostream.h`, it's just `iostream`.

Comment: Really? So when the tutorial's files say `#include <iostream.h>` it should say `#include <iostream>`?

Comment: Well, the tutorial's probably old enough that it was valid when it was written.

Comment: That tutorial links to the Make documentation for a version (3.79.1) which was released **June 23rd, 2000**. You might consider finding a newer tutorial.

Comment: wow... can you recommend a newer tut?

Comment: As a tutorial for learning make, it looks fine to me.  It's only the C++ that's the problem, and you should be learning that from a separate source anyway.

Comment: For others: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iostream.h, fstream.h cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225277/iostream-h-fstream-h-cannot-be-found)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Before the C++ language was standardized by the ISO, the header file was named `<iostream.h>`, but when the C++98 standard was released, it was renamed to just `<iostream>` (without the `.h`).  Change the code to use `#include <iostream>` instead and it should compile.

You'll also need to add a `using namespace std;` statement to each source file (or prefix each reference to an iostream function/object with a `std::` specifier), since namespaces did not exist in the pre-standardized C++.  C++98 put the standard library functions and objects inside the `std` namespace.

Comment: In C++<98 edition, it was at one time named `<iostream.h>`, but that was before even namespaces were introduced.

Comment: C++98 didn't have `<iostream.h>`. The `.h` forms of C++ header names came from the pre-standard days of cfront, Glockenspiel C++, Comeau, Zortech, and Borland. The C++98 standard removed the suffix and put all the names in namespace `std`. Some implementations still provide the `.h` headers for backward compatibility.

Comment: I don't think this was worth being downvoted on. Sure, you made a mistake but everyone does. The rest of your answer is correct, just because your history is off doesn't mean I should downvote you. It's easy to fix.

Comment: @Alf et al.: Yeesh, sorry, I misremembered history.  One downvote, ok, but 3?  That's a little excessive.  Please see the edited answer.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield +1 with the edit. Regardless: Misremembering may not be a big deal; misrepresenting, though, is unnecessary on SO. I actually love that SO is good for a broader perspective on things too. It's a community for this reason.

Answer (score 14):

`<iostream.h>` has never been a standard C++ header, because it did not make it into the C++ standard.

Instead we got `<iostream>`, in 1998.

Steer well clear of teaching material using non-standard stuff such as `<iostream.h>` or `void main`.

However, as a practical solution for your current pre-standard code, you may try to replace

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

with

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

It’s not guaranteed to work, but chances are that it will work.

Comment: The better solution (imho) is to not have `using namespace std;` and instead add `std::` in front of the standard names.

Answer (score 2):

Another related issue that wasn't mentioned here, so I will include it for anyone's future reference, is from the command line the compiler needs the environment path variable updated to find the location of the c++ header files. In windows you can just update the path environment using the 'advanced system properties' GUI and add the location of the c++ include files. This will update the PATH environment variable in Windows cmd & Cygwin automatically upon restarting the shell.

To update your PATH from Linux or the Cygwin shell type... 
PATH=$PATH:/your_path_here 
Example:PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/cygwin/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.3/include/c++
Also a good idea to add just the include directory as well: 
PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/cygwin/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.3/include/
...or check the proper directories for the location of your installation's include files, I recommend installing mingw for use with Cygwin, which is envoked with g++.

To install additional needed packages in Cygwin re-run the Cygwin install utility & check install from Internet to add packages from web repositories and add mingw-gcc-g++ & mingw-binutils.
To compile: g++ hello.cpp -o hello

If using the gcc utility instead compile with the command:
gcc hello.cpp -o hello -lstdc++
... to get your executable.

As long as you have either gcc or mingw installed and the path to the c++ include files is in your path environment variable, the commands will work.

Comment: Wrong. PATH environment variable is used to specify locations of executables. The path to include files for gcc/g++ is specified in CPATH environment variable.