# fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++

I am using GCC 4.6.3:

```
gourab@gourab-RV509:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

My program results in the following compilation error:

```
gourab@gourab-RV509:~$ g++ ArrayInput.cpp
ArrayInput.cpp:1:21: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Typically you want to use the `<iostream>` includes.  Perhaps they're already on the default include path?

Comment: after resolving the issue and recompiling i get this error:-                 gourab@gourab-RV509:~$ g++ ArrayInput.cpp
ArrayInput.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ArrayInput.cpp:5:2: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
ArrayInput.cpp:5:2: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:62:18: note:   ‘std::cout’
ArrayInput.cpp:8:5: error: ‘cin’ was not declared in this scope
ArrayInput.cpp:8:5: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:61:18: note:   ‘std::cin’

Comment: @grv.giit Which book are you using ?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: sorry to say you but i have coding and programming experience in windows platform . I'm new to Linux. That's why i just got confused many times... :)

Comment: @grv.giit: It's just the same in Windows.

Comment: @AshRj:- thanks for the concern friend !! i am using my college notes of C++ OOPS which is having academic syllabus of our university.. :)

Comment: @grv.giit Get a proper book. Those notes will get you through the semester but wont help you beyond that. Its better if you use a proper book, referring to the notes only for the topics to study. And DONT go for any Indian authored textbook.

Comment: http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/iostream.html :- This link  solved many issues i got !! a thumps up to all of you...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't g++ find iostream.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103108/why-cant-g-find-iostream-h)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to include `iostream`. `iostream.h` was present in Stroustrup's C++:

> The original iostream library was written to challenge the claim that
>   a terse, type safe I/O system needed special language support. [1](http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/iostream.html) It
>   was developed at Bell Labs by Bjarne Stroustrup and shipped with the
>   original C++ compiler, CFront and described in the first edition of
>   Stroustrup's The C++ Programming Language. This version of the
>   iostream library lived in the headers iostream.h, fstream.h and so on.

The Standard C++ has the headers without the .h, so you want to:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Here is an [article](http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/iostream.html) that discusses this.

Comment: Not deprecated; it does not exist in standard C++ at all, and _never did_.

Answer (score 11):

`iostream.h` has not existed in C++ since some time before the language was standardised back in 1998.

That's more than fifteen years ago.

Do the following:

- Throw away your reading material
- Get a [decent](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources) [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)
- `#include <iostream>` — *no `.h`*