# C++ <iostream.h> Error

Tags: c++

I am at the absolutely newest level of new when it comes to C++. It may seem like a noob mistake, but I think I'm missing something with my first program, "Hello World!".

I'm running from Ubuntu (not sure if this is any different from working with Windows), and I'm using a book called *Teach Yourself C++ in 21 Days*.

The code I'm resembling looks exactly like this:

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main()
{
cout <<"Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I have this exactly in my text editor, but I keep getting greeted by the same error whenever I try to compile it!

> first.cpp:2:22: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

I'm pretty distressed as this is literally the first step in my coding career! I'm not sure if ubuntu needs to be treated differently than Windows (which is what the book is using as reference).

Help!

Comment: `#include <iostream>`

Comment: `<iostream.h>` isn't a proper thing; use `<iostream>`.

Comment: You might want to use a better book: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: You have a very old edition of "Teach Yourself C++ in 21 Days".  The newest edition doesn't make this mistake (or the mistake of leaving off the `std` qualifier from `cout`). Note that these problems probably were not mistakes when the book you have was published due to the fact that the language changed in many details when it was standardized. You should get the newer edition or consider Blastfurnace's suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't g++ find iostream.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103108/why-cant-g-find-iostream-h)

Answer (score 7):

There are two problems here:

You need to omit the `.h` suffix:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Also, `cout` is an unqualified name, and needs to be qualified with the `std` namespace since you are not `using namespace std`:

```
std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any `iostream.h` it's simply called `iostream` and should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
std::cout <<"Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

(also notice the `std::` before the cout, since it means that it's from the standard namespace.)

Answer (score 0):

You want just iostream

```
#include <iostream>
```

I suspect the book is very old.  Names are qualified in the std namespace, so you may want to add

```
using namespace std;
```

For now at least.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
#include <iostream>
```

in general STL header file don't have a .h

Comment: No standard C++ headers have an extension. By that, I exclude the C ones that are included in C++.

Answer (score -2):

you need to compile using g++ compiler, not by gcc

g++ hello.cpp