# Missing iostream.h file from MinGW?

Tags: c++, mingw, iostream

I need this file for tutorials, but I can't find it anywhere on the internet. Help somebody?

Comment: its iostream, not iostream.h

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't g++ find iostream.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103108/why-cant-g-find-iostream-h)

Comment: "not working" is not a question. No one can answer it without knowing the configuration

Answer (score 4):

Any tutorial that uses `iostream.h` is twenty years out of date; that header was used in pre-standard C++, but has never been part of the ISO standard. Find a newer tutorial; one that uses `iostream`.

Comment: I used <iostream>, but still can't use it. Also Eclipse can't be configured to work correctly, no matter what I do.

Answer (score 1):

The iostream library is usually called just `iostream` in most IDE's. Just `#include <iostream>` should do.