# Compiling c++ program in ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gnu

There is a problem in compiling in C++ program

> error: iostream.h no such file or directory

I used make hello where `hello.cpp` is my filename.

Comment: Try #include <iostream>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't g++ find iostream.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103108/why-cant-g-find-iostream-h)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
#include<iostream>
```

The name *iostream.h* is deprecated.

Comment: Not just deprecated; it hasn't been a standard header since at least 1998.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes, you're right. This is quite well explained in the link I provided in my answer.

Comment: According to "The C++ Standard Library" by Josuttis, it's deprecated. From page 41: *"there is no specification in the standard. Hence, they are not supported. In practice, most vendors will probably provide them to enable backward compatibility"*

Answer (score 1):

Use `#include <iostream>` instead of `#include <iostream.h>`

If you want to know why `iostream.h` was outdated, I suggest reading: [Why is #include  outdated](http://www.cpp-home.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=252)

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
```

that is the first code I ve write

Comment: You should never use *using namespace std* in headers.

Comment: Maybe this is the first Hello World of his programing career, do you want him konw those complex rules

Comment: @Patato, ideally - yes.

Comment: @Patato: Using properly qualified names is no more "complex" than learning an incantation to dump them into the wrong namespace, and is a better habit to get into.