# #include<iostream.h> works well in turboc++ but not in Visual studio. why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, turbo-c++

I'm using turboc++ 4.0 and Visual studio 2013. I just started learning programming. when I write the code.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
cout<<"hello!";
getch();
return 0;
}
```

it works well in turbo, but visual stdio shows an error

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream.h': No such file or directory.

and when I use

```
using namespace std;
```

it shows another error about using `getch();`.

**Does every compiler have its own syntax?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't g++ find iostream.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103108/why-cant-g-find-iostream-h)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Does every compiler have it's own syntax?"*

No, there's a standard every compiler needs to implement.
Turbo-C++ was made before any standards were established and is merely the only compiler still around, that doesn't implement them.

The standard compliant way to write your program looks like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout<<"hello!" << std::endl;
    char dummy;
    std::cin >> dummy;
}
```

---

<sub>**Note:** You shouldn't use **[`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)**, but explicitly put the `std::` scope when needed, or use `using std::cout cout;`, etc.</sub>

Comment: The note is very bad advice in two ways: (1) our language features are there for us to use as appropriate, and `using namespace std;` is often appropriate, where one appropriate case is the one of making pre-standard code work with modern compilers, and (2) it gives the impression that such *don't think, just follow a mechanical rule blindly* approach is useful and practical. It isn't. The end result of blindly following mechanical rules is very low quality, complex code, and much wasted time.

Comment: In particular, in the present case, the work to qualify all relevant identifiers in the case with `std::`, can be prohibitive. So it's very bad advice indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Turbo C++ is from the middle or early 1990's, before the standardization of C++.

At that time the effective standard for C++ was the ARM, the *Annotated Reference Manual* by Bjarne Stroustrup and Margaret Ellis (IIRC), and it used `<iostream.h>`.

With the first standardization in 1998 `<iostream.h>` was dropped, and replaced with just `<iostream>`. The standard header places `cin` and `cout` in namespace `std`, so you can't just change the header name. It's not guaranteed, but you *may* possibly be able to make your code work by writing

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```