# Compile pre c++98 project?

Tags: c++, g++5.1

Trying to compile old (legacy) cpp project. As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/13103121/555493, this project is older than C++98!

Is there any way to compile this project without some type of (minor) refactoring?

When I run the command `g++ -std=c++98 -pedantic -ggdb  -c file.cxx` it errs out with the error `fatal error: 'iostream.h' file not found`.

Note: I am not the author of the original code. Migrating to a more modern version of C++ is likely out of the question. So for now, I'm just trying to get it to compile.

I'm using brew, gcc5, on a mac El Capitan.

```
gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir:   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: It's `iostream` without `.h`

Comment: @Danh see my update. It's legacy code (10+ years old). Refactoring is likely out of the question

Comment: OMG @Danh, as per that link, this seems to be older than c++98!!!

Comment: decide it yourself, standardized C++ never has anything like `iostream.h`

Comment: @danh ??? "decide it yourself".

Comment: Upgrade to standardized C++ or not. If you choose to upgrade to standardized C++, go for C++14

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128021/discussion-between-u-avalos-and-danh).

Comment: @r-sahu no this is not a duplicate. I'm asking how to compile an old project, not why it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to compile this project without some type of (minor) refactoring?

If you are allowed to add .h files to the project, you could create `iostream.h` with the following:

```
#ifndef MY_IOSTREAM_H
#define MY_IOSTREAM_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#endif
```

and then make sure that the directory where the file lives is added to the list of directories to search for `#include`d files.

**Disclaimer**

This does not guarantee that you won't have to change anything else. Who knows what platform specific pre-C++98 features are used in the code base of such an old project.